# How can I get better results using DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I am solving my fourth-order differential equation by using DSolve. When I solved it gives me an error related to precision. How can I improve my results and get better output? Any help will be appreciated.

```
t = 1/10; Da = 10^-4; \[Epsilon] = 9/10; k = 10; Bi = 1/10; Br = 10;
A0 = Sqrt[\[Epsilon]]/Sqrt[Da];
A1 = Da + t^2/2 - Da Sech[(-1 + t)*A0] - (Sqrt[Da] t Tanh[(-1 + t)*A0])/\[Epsilon]^(3/2);
A2 = (Sqrt[Da] Sech[(-1 + t)*A0] (-t Cosh[A0] + Sqrt[Da] \[Epsilon]^(3/2) Sinh[t A0]))/\[Epsilon]^(3/2);
A3 = -((Sqrt[Da] Sech[(-1 + t)*A0] (Sqrt[Da] \[Epsilon]^(3/2) Cosh[t A0] - t Sinh[A0]))/\[Epsilon]^(3/2));
A6 = (Bi*(1 + k))/k;
Uc = -(Y^2/2) + A1;
Upm = A2*Sinh[Y*A0] + A3*Cosh[Y*A0] + Da;
Um = FullSimplify[Integrate[Uc, {Y, 0, t}] + Integrate[Upm, {Y, t, 1}]];
B1 = 1/(12 A0 Um^2 \[Epsilon]) (-6 A0^3 (A2 - A3) (A2 + A3) Br Da (-1 + t) + 2 A0 (3 A2^2 Br (-1 + t) - 3 A3^2 Br (-1 + t) + 2 Br Da (3 Da - 3 Da t + t^3) + 6 Um^2) \[Epsilon] + 3 Br (-8 A2 Da \[Epsilon] Cosh[A0 t] - 2 A2 A3 (A0^2 Da + \[Epsilon]) Cosh[2 A0 t] + 2 (A2 Cosh[A0] + A3 Sinh[A0]) (4 Da \[Epsilon] + (A0^2 Da + \[Epsilon]) (A3 Cosh[A0] + A2 Sinh[A0])) - 8 A3 Da [Epsilon] Sinh[A0 t] - (A2^2 + A3^2) (A0^2 Da + \[Epsilon]) Sinh[2 A0 t]));
B2 = -((2 Br Da t^3 + B1 t (-6 A1 + t^2) Um)/(6 Um^2));
B3 = -((A0^2 Br Da (A2 Cosh[A0] + A3 Sinh[A0])^2)/(k Um^2 \[Epsilon]));
B4 = (B1 Um (Da + A3 Cosh[A0 t] + A2 Sinh[A0 t]) - Br (Da + A3 Cosh[A0 t] + A2 Sinh[A0 t])^2 - (A0^2 Br Da (A2 Cosh[A0 t] + A3 Sinh[A0 t])^2)/\[Epsilon])/(k Um^2);
C1 = (A2 (A0^2 - Bi) (2 Br Da - B1 Um) )/(k Um^2);
C2 = (A2 A3 (4 A0^2 - Bi) Br (A0^2 Da + \[Epsilon]) )/(k Um^2 \[Epsilon]);
C3 = (A3 (A0^2 - Bi) (2 Br Da - B1 Um))/(k Um^2);
C4 = ((A2^2 + A3^2) (4 A0^2 - Bi) Br (A0^2 Da + \[Epsilon]) )/(2 k Um^2 \[Epsilon]);
C5 = (Bi (A0^2 (-A2^2 + A3^2) Br Da + (A2^2 Br - A3^2 Br - 2 Br Da^2 + 2 B1 Da Um) \[Epsilon]))/(2 k Um^2 \[Epsilon]);
C6 = (A2 Bi (-2 Br Da + B1 Um) )/(k Um^2);
C7 = -((A2 A3 Bi Br (A0^2 Da + \[Epsilon]) )/(k Um^2 \[Epsilon]));
C8 = (A3 Bi (-2 Br Da + B1 Um) )/(k Um^2);
C9 = -(((A2^2 + A3^2) Bi Br (A0^2 Da + \[Epsilon]) )/(2 k Um^2 \[Epsilon]));
eqn1 = X''''[Y] - A6*X''[Y] + C1 Sinh[A0 Y] + C2 Sinh[2 A0 Y] + C3 Cosh[A0 Y] + C4 Cosh[2 A0 Y] + C5 == 0;
eqn2 = Z''''[Y] - A6*Z''[Y] + C6 Sinh[A0 Y] + C7 Sinh[2 A0 Y] + C8 Cosh[A0 Y] + C9 Cosh[2 A0 Y] + C5 == 0;
system = {eqn1, eqn2, X''[1] == B3, Z''[1] == 0, k*X'[1] + Z'[1] == 1,X[1] == Z[1], X[t] == 0, Z[t] == 0, X''[t] == B4, Z''[t] == 0 };
{solX, solY} = DSolveValue[system, {X[Y], Z[Y]}, Y]; // Simplify

f = Table[N[solX[Y], 16], {Y, 1/10, 1, 1/100}
```

I am getting this error.

```
Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50.` reached
```

Comment: version numbers?

Comment: I am using Mathematica 10 and I have also checked in 11.3.

Comment: Are your results still correct?

Comment: Not yet still a problem.

Comment: @Nasser I have simplified the equation further and now it's taking less time to process. The results still the same. if you don't mind you can check again.